# How do I align an inner div with the bottom of an outer div?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need to align an inner div with the bottom of an outer div.

My code looks like this:

```
<div class="myOuterDiv">
    <div class="div1 floatLeft"> Variable content here </div>
    <div class="div2 floatRight"> <img class="myButton" src="" /> </div>
</div>
```

The content of 'div1' may vary, making the height of the outer div to vary.
How can I make sure that my button (div2) always stays at the bottom of the outer div?

I prefer using CSS, but if not possible, I can use jQuery.

**UPDATE**

I chose to do this the jQuery way, where I bumped into some issues. It's all solved and you can find my working solution here:[How can I calculate the height of an element cross-browser using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043321/how-can-i-calculate-the-height-of-an-element-cross-browser-using-jquery)

Comment: So you have a left and a right column and the button in the right column needs to be at the bottom no matter the length of the left column, correct?

Comment: Yup, that's right. I probably don't even need the DIV around the button (?).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
.myOuterDiv { position: relative; }
.div2 { position: absolute; bottom: 0 }
```

Making something position absolute **will remove it from the flow**; you could account for this by adding bottom padding to .myOuterDiv that is equivalent to the height of .div2

Comment: That would work if the outerdiv was static. But I have several outer divs in different heights on the page. I tried something similar before I asked here, and it didn't work.

Comment: I'm accepting this solution, since it's the most common one used.

Answer (score 1):

Mike's solution works well in all browsers.  Here's my code using his idea that did what you wanted:

```
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #wrapper
        {           
            overflow: auto;
            position: relative;
        }        
        #left
        {
            float: left;
            width: 300px;
            margin-right: 10px;
        }
        #right
        {
            width: 200px;
            float: left;
        }
        #bottom
        {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="left">
            Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.

The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.
        </div>
        <div id="right">
            <div id="bottom"><input type="button" value="Testing"  /></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would have help but I'm on mobile. But this is just a hint using jquery.

Get the height value of the two div's. Subtract the height values from each other.
Now control the margin-top of the right div using the value of the result to push it down.

I'll check back no this if I am on my desk or laptop.

Comment: Don't know why u get downvoted, but this is the way I currently am testing out, by creating my own jQuery plugin. not quite working, but almost.

Comment: It's been about a dozen years. Did you get a chance to get to your desktop or laptop yet? :)

Answer (score 0):

Your comment implies that you will only have the image in the `div` and nothing else. In which case, you could set it as a background image, aligned to the bottom:

```
<style>
.myOuterDiv {
    background: transparent url("myButton.png") no-repeat right bottom;
}
</style>

<div class="myOuterDiv">
    <div class="div1 floatLeft"> Variable content here </div>
</div>
```

Instead of `right bottom` you can use `left bottom` or `center bottom` if you want that instead. You might not need the inner `div` either.