# setting a div at the bottom of an outer div

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

i'm having a problem with some CSS

i have *N* outside-divs, with variable, dynamic height.
every outside-div will have ONE inside-div, which should be at the bottom of the outside div.

so, using the trick with position absolute like in [How do I align an inner div with the bottom of an outer div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042643/how-do-i-align-an-inner-div-with-the-bottom-of-an-outer-div) is not possible.

I made a jsfiddle for you to play around:
 http://jsfiddle.net/xSTtp/4/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="outside">
    <div class="inside">
        xyz
    </div>
</div>
<div class="outside">
    <div class="inside">
        xyz
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.outside { 
    /* the height will be dynamic, 100px is just for the demo */
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid green;
}

.inside {
    border: 1px solid red;
    /* not working*/
    /*  display: table-cell;
            vertical-align: bottom;
            */
    /* i want the red at the bottom of the green, not in the page */
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Thanks 
Joerg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why is position: absolute; bottom: 0; not possible?

The wrapper div or parent div needs to have a `position: relative;` or `position: absolute;` for it to position the child at the bottom.

```
.outside { 
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid green;
}

.inside {
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid red;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: damned, i feel stupid now, haven't used the `position: relative;` thanks a lot, i will accept the answer in a few minutes, when i'm allowed to!

Comment: ... i have now a new jsfiddle with the "real" problem: http://jsfiddle.net/USaVa/3/

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/xSTtp/6/ If you know the height of the parent div, you can just specify top: [parent height-child height]

Comment: That does not meet his requirements. His divs have variable dynamic height so the height is not known.

Comment: Ah, then he should use your answer.

Comment: right, Marks solution is working... i just haven used it without the `position: relative;` works perfect now...